# Is there a way to change error handling message when using PHP Form Builder Class framework?

Tags: php, ajax, form-post

I want to get the fields that have errors and display a different message than showed below:

```
The following 3 errors were found:
Error: field1 is a required field.
Error: field2 is a required field.
Error: field3 is a required field.
```

This code handles the errors:

```
if(isset($_POST["form"])) {
    if(Form::isValid($_POST["form"])) {
      //ok
    }
    else
                //prints the errors
        Form::renderAjaxErrorResponse($_POST["form"]);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: find and edit  renderAjaxErrorResponse()

Comment: I found Required.php and changed the class "Validation_Required". This solves my problem but I not what I really want. It's a shame that this framework does not have a way to pass the message you want to display.

Comment: anything "pre-made" has the issue of not being 100% what you want - so i never use a framework.